# Need to know why I am not able to count the element(s) inside my stream named "empStream"

Tags: java, stream

I am passing a list to create/generate a stream and count the elements of that stream. What i understand is that my "empStream" contains only one element which is list of Employee. According to java docs the stream is closed once it gets consumed/used and we cannot perform other operations on that stream.But here i have not consumed empStream anywhere before "empStream.count();" statement.
So why "empStream.count();" is not getting executed.

````
 public class AAAproblem1 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
         list.add(new Employee(6, "Nick", 27, "Software Engineer"));
         list.add(new Employee(9, "Tom", 23, "Civil Engineer"));
         list.add(new Employee(3, "Jon", 29, "Mechanical Engineer"));
         list.add(new Employee(4, "Harry", 21, "Surgeon"));
         list.add(new Employee(8, "Don", 25, "Laywer"));
         list.add(new Employee(7, "Marry", 20, "Police"));
         list.add(new Employee(2, "Angel", 22, "Professor"));
         list.add(new Employee(1, "Kate", 23, "Teacher"));
         list.add(new Employee(5, "Evan", 22, "Pilot"));

         generateStream(list);
    }

    private static void generateStream(List<Employee> list) {
        Stream<List<Employee>> empStream = Stream.generate(() -> {
            return list;
        });
       empStream.onClose(()->{System.out.println("empStream is closed");});
       System.out.println("counting number of list inside empStream started");
       // not able to count the elements inside emp stream
       long items = empStream.count();
       System.out.println("counting number of list inside empStream finished");
       System.out.println("The number of employee list in streams is/are - " + items);
       empStream.onClose(()->{System.out.println("empStream is closed");});
    }
 }
 ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stream.generate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) returns an *infinite* sequential unordered stream by calling the supplier. In this case, the stream produced is an infinite stream where each element is the list.

You cannot apply the `count` operation to an *infinite* stream. You need some short-circuiting operation (like `limit`) to convert the stream generated by the `generate` method to a finite stream ([as shown here](https://javadevcentral.com/seven-ways-to-create-a-stream-in-java#2_Stream_generate_method))

`list.stream().count()` is what you want here.